# Codeigniter select by supplierid

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to select products by supplierid but code seems to return every product from database, I cant figure it out why but it must be something I am missing as I am not an expert in codeigniter, ireally apretiate your input on this, thx

```
    -----Controller page-----



    {

    $this->data['store_products'] = $this->productss->get_products_by_supplier_id();
    $this->data['store_suppliers'] = $this->productss->get_join_suppliers();
    $this->data['tax_settings'] = $this->productss->get_all_taxs();
    $this->data['store_taxs'] = $this->productss->get_join_taxs();
           
    $this->load->view('products/by_supplier', $this->data);
    }




    ----------- Model page-----




    public function get_products_by_supplier_id()
     {
            $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('store_products');

    $this->db->join('store_suppliers', 'store_products.supplierid = store_suppliers.supplierid','left');

    $this->db->join('tax_settings', 'store_products.taxid = tax_settings.taxid','left');

    $this->db->where('store_suppliers.supplierid',$supplierid);
        
        
            $query =  $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
    return $query->result_array();
    }
    else
    {
    return array();
    }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to remove the parameter 'left' in the join query?

Answer (score 0):

change this lines. the order of the comparison is important. I change it and run the query.

```
 $this->db->join('store_suppliers', ' store_suppliers.supplierid = store_products.supplierid');

 $this->db->join('tax_settings', 'tax_settings.taxid =store_products.taxid');
```

Answer (score 0):

from where u will get the $supplierid

```
$this->db->where('store_suppliers.supplierid',$supplierid);
```

pass supplier id here

```
get_products_by_supplier_id() to
get_products_by_supplier_id($supplierid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorted, url on index page wasn't properly passing the parameter.

was using -

removing base 64 encode solve the problem